# Calculating Cumulative Probability from a population x

Tags: python, loops, probability

How can I go about creating a function (let’s call it birthday(x) ) that calculates the probability, `p(x)`, of at least two people having the same birthday (ignoring leap year) with a loop? The formula of the probability is:

`p(x) = 1−365/365⋅364/365⋅363/365…(366−x)/365`

I’m guessing I should reiterate the formula for a given number, `x`, but unsure how. Thanks in advance!

Edit: `x` is the number of people among which at least two have the same birthday.

Comment: I don't understand. The probability of 2 people having the same birthday is 1/365. What is the loop needed?

Comment: @ThePilotDude because it seems to be 2 people among a population of x

Comment: Oh that makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

```
#For y peoples; Or for y plays of roulette and x outcomes
def odds(x,y):
    return x/x**y

print (odds(365,2))


#For at least 2 peoples within a group of n peoples
import math 

def grp_odds(x,n):
    return 1-math.factorial(x)/(x**n*math.factorial(x-n))

print (grp_odds(365,2))
print (grp_odds(365,5))
```

Output:

```
0.0027397260273972603
0.002739726027397249
0.02713557369979358
```

You could make it fancier by thinking how about Feb. 29th ;)

Comment: Your formula only works in case the population, what he names `x` is also 2. What he is asking is how the probabilty of finding at least 2 people in a group of x changes depending on the value of x. The chances of having 2 guys with birthday in the same day is not the group is formed by `x=2` guys than lets say `x=366`

Comment: Check his edit: "x is the number of people among which at least two have the same birthday". The probability changes with the size of the group. Is what I was explaning you in the comment before. If x=2, it will be the value you gave. If the group is 366, you now for sure that at least two guys are gonna have their birthdays the same day, so will be much higher than 0.0027

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to calculate is the [Cumulative Probability of a Binomial Distribution](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/s10-binomial-distribution-1/tutorial). So for a population of `x` you want to know the probability that at least 2 individual have their birthdays in the same day. You can use this:

```
import math

# x is the size of your population
def birthday(x):
    # Probability of having birthay in a specific day of the year
    p = 1/365 
    q = 1-p

    acc = 0
    
    # Summing from 2 until size of population (you need at least 2)
    for i in range(2,x+1):
        acc += (math.factorial(n)*(p**i)*(q**(n-i)))/(math.factorial(i)*math.factorial(n-i))
        
    return acc
```